# Subset Dataframe of Duplicate Values by Max Date

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates

I have a sample dataset below:

```
df

      Date    Col1    Col2    Col3   Col4   Col5
2019-02-25       A       A       B      4      7
2019-02-26       A       A       B     10      9
2019-02-24       B       C       D      9     12
2019-02-23       J       M       L     19     18
2019-02-23       B       C       D     11     78
```

How do I subset my dataset so that if there are duplicates from `df[,2:4]`, I only keep the max Date out of those duplicates? I still want the unique values from the previous table to be present.

Final expected output:

```
      Date    Col1    Col2    Col3   Col4   Col5
2019-02-26       A       A       B     10      9
2019-02-24       B       C       D      9     12
2019-02-23       J       M       L     19     18
```

Comment: `df[!duplicated(df[2:4]),]` or `df %>% group_by_at(2:4) %>% slice(which.max(Date))`

Comment: the last part `df %>% group_by_at(2:4) %>% slice(which.max(Date))` was what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `tidyverse`.  After grouping by columns 2 to 4, `slice` the row based on the index of `max`imum 'Date'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by_at(2:4) %>% 
  slice(which.max(Date))
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df[with(df, ave(Date, Col1, Col2, Col3, FUN = max) == Date),]
```

Answer (score 1):

A built-in solution which uses `aggregate()` in `stats`:

```
merge(df, aggregate(Date ~ Col1 + Col2 + Col3, df, max))
```